# Error while entring Ubuntu SSO credentials during snappy core installation on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: email, ubuntu-core

I am getting an error when I try to enter my email ID during the snappy core installation on raspberry pi 3.

The error reads as:

```
**Creating user failed:**

**error: while creating user: cannot create user "email ID": Get https://login.ubuntu.com/api/v2/keys/emailID: dial tcp: lookup login.ubuntu.com on 10.58.194.16:53: no such host**
```

I already have an ubuntu account with the mail ID specified here as *email ID*. Can anyone kindly guide me as to how to get past this error? Just so you know, I am what I call as a noob_level developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a network error. I was using a network which had a lot of restrictions and thus couldn't connect to the login page of ubuntu.